# Is it possible to target the value of a html element in Django template language?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
<h1 class='username'>something</h1>

{% if request.user|stringify == .username %}
```

Is something like this possible or not?

Comment: No, and not in the dynamic way I believe you're trying to do it since the template syntax is rendered server side in comparision to your setting of the username clientside. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I've got a profile div with a logout form(button) inside it. I only want to show the logout button if the `h1` username in that div == the logged in user

Comment: Without a full [mcve] its going to be hard to answer this (I.e is it always the logged in user looking at the page?) `request.user.is_authenticated` may be enough....

Comment: @Zorgan the text **something** is a variable  **{{ username }}** right??

Comment: @Zorgan Post the exact HTML code with template variables as they are. And also the view from which this template is rendered.

Comment: @Sayse No, the profile div can be of any user. @prakhar-trivedi No the text changes from an ajax call like this `$('.username').html(data.username);`  I know it's hard to answer without all the code so I don't mind i'll just find another way, I just wanted to know an answer to the original question

Comment: @Zorgan Then you can use jquery and javascript for the if condition. If you show the exact js code,then I can help you further.

Comment: You're right I can do it inside the jQuery function by comparing `$('.username').html(data.username);` to a `data.logged_in_user`. I should be able to get it now, thanks.

Comment: @Zorgan You can use **data.logged_in_user** or **{{ request.user }}** both. But according to your question the later one would be better. Included in my answer

Comment: This is strange, you just wrote "class='username'" in the template yourself. Surely you don't have to look up its value when you just generated that value.

Comment: There is nothing like an html element inside your template. It is plain text, that will be rendered and send to the client. You could basicly render every kind of text document with a django template. As you generate the text inside the template yourself you should already know it's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your html code of **Logout** button is like this:

```
<h1 class='username'>something</h1>
<button class='logoutbtn'>Logout</button>
```

Then you can hide the logout button with the javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.username').html(data.username);

    if (data.username != "{{ request.user }}" ) 
        { 
         $('.logoutbtn').hide();
        }

</script>
```

Or based on the data.logged_in_user like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.username').html(data.username);

    if (data.username != data.logged_in_user ) 
        { 
         $('.logoutbtn').hide();
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do this. You're getting confused on what is client side and what is server side. Your dynamic html code is handled through Javascript - which is client side. Where as Django Template Languange is used server side where it produces a rendered html page (which is what the javascript sees)

From your use case I'd imagine that

```
 {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

*might* be enough since your log out button should hopefully be obvious enough that it is to log out the user seeing the page.

Alternatively, you can just hide it with javascript and then secure the view more to make sure that the request user does have permission to do the logging out.